# Intellij Community Edition showing this error on schema.sql file as can see on image that I droped here

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, jdbc, h2

[image]

When I run the application this shutdown and don't allow me enter on H2 database on localhost h2 URL.
Is anyone else having this same problem?

```
:: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.1)

2020-12-22 15:23:08.377  INFO 4937 --- [  restartedMain] c.l.suraapp.SuraAppApplication           : Starting SuraAppApplication using Java 15 on goemon with PID 4937 (/home/leporoni/Documents/JavaProjects/SuraApp/target/classes started by leporoni in /home/leporoni/Documents/JavaProjects/SuraApp)
2020-12-22 15:23:08.381  INFO 4937 --- [  restartedMain] c.l.suraapp.SuraAppApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-12-22 15:23:08.554  INFO 4937 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-12-22 15:23:10.115  INFO 4937 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-12-22 15:23:10.228  INFO 4937 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 84 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-12-22 15:23:11.011  INFO 4937 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-12-22 15:23:11.580  INFO 4937 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-12-22 15:23:11.836  INFO 4937 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-12-22 15:23:11.972  INFO 4937 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.25.Final
2020-12-22 15:23:12.653  INFO 4937 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2020-12-22 15:23:12.967  INFO 4937 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2020-12-22 15:23:13.927  INFO 4937 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-12-22 15:23:13.941  INFO 4937 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-12-22 15:23:13.959  INFO 4937 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-12-22 15:23:14.520  INFO 4937 --- [  restartedMain] c.l.suraapp.SuraAppApplication           : Started SuraAppApplication in 7.451 seconds (JVM running for 9.275)
2020-12-22 15:23:14.529  INFO 4937 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-12-22 15:23:14.564  INFO 4937 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-12-22 15:23:14.581  INFO 4937 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: How is screenshot related to the log you provided?

Comment: There is too little information in your question to be able to answer it. At first glance, it looks like you are just writing a command-line application (no web-related things) which will shutdown directly after it has done its job.

Comment: The script you show is for MySQL, yet you mention using H2. The problem might also be that you configured IntelliJ to use the wrong dialect (although I thought that was only an Ultimate feature).

Comment: @M.Deinum The image capture I provided was to show the two errors in the schema.sql file, since the log was to find out why after I start the application I can't access the URL of the H2 bank.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Seriously, this script doesn't work with H2 then? How could I do it to work well with H2? About the problem that Intellij Community presents, I also imagined that it would be due to not having Ultimate installed, but I took a course these days ago in which the teacher uses this same script with H2, so I am surprised that I am not giving right.

Comment: Again, the proces stops. As the proces stops there is nothing to access.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I got it now, bad begginer question :) Tks.